# Is there a way to make Ubuntu 18.04 login screen dark themed?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, login, themes, gdm

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 using Communitheme, managed to make it dark within the desktop environment; the Nautilus is dark, the menus are all dark and browsers are also respectively dark themed. Everything looks great EXCEPT for the Login Screen which is white.

It's the window where you enter your password when you login. That window is white as opposed to the rest of the setup.

How do I go about making it black or dark or not-so-bright-white?

***Edit (09/09/2019):***

It's a success but there is still some white on the first screen (before you click enter and see the Password: field). And I need to change the text colour to white in contrast to the dark background.

[image: Dark text]

***Edit 2 (09/09/2019):***

The second screen is completely sorted. This is the bit I was talking about -- the background is still bright. I'd like to make it the same colour as its surrounding which is dark.

[image: Still bright..]

Comment: I think it's both. At the login screen, I can select Communitheme on Xorg (from the cogwheel) and once logged in, I can also select it from Ubuntu Tweaks -> Appearance -> Themes -> Applications drop-down menu.

Comment: @PRATAP I don't want to change the login screen's background, it's already dark. I mean the actually login screen bit, the window.

Communitheme's repo is ppa:communitheme/ppa
Package name is ubuntu-communitheme-session

Comment: @PRATAP
The output as below:  
There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).  

  Selection    Path                                                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/communitheme/gnome-shell.css   15        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/communitheme/gnome-shell.css   15        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css                     10        manual mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Be Careful while editing the gdm3.css or its original file.. small mistakes in code.. will not let you login.. you need special support to bring back things to normal.. Proceed with your own.***

1. Take backup of the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/communitheme/gnome-shell.css`
2. Open the file with gedit

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/communitheme/gnome-shell.css
   ```

   Look for the fields below

   ```
   .login-dialog {
     border: none;
     background-color: transparent; }
     .login-dialog > StBoxLayout {
       background-color: green;
       border: 1px solid #cccccc;
       box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       border-radius: 6px;
       padding: 12px 40px 24px 40px; }
   ```

   Change `green` to any valid color as you wish in the above field

   ```
   .login-dialog-user-list {
     spacing: 12px;
     padding: .2em;
     width: 23em; }
     .login-dialog-user-list:expanded .login-dialog-user-list-item:selected {
       background-color: blue;
       color: #ffffff; }
     .login-dialog-user-list:expanded .login-dialog-user-list-item:logged-in {
       border-right: 2px solid #E95420; }
   ```

   Change `blue` to any valid color as you wish in the above field.
3. Save the file, close & reboot to see the change in action.

   [image]

***Edit 09/09/2019***

```
.login-dialog-username,
.user-widget-label {
  color: magenta;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px; }
```

and

```
.login-dialog-prompt-label {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 110%;
  padding-top: 1em; }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it and managed to change the colours to dark BUT now I'm trying to change the text to white lol.  
How is CSS referring to the text? I've played around with it but can't seem to be able to find the references.

Comment: "PRATAP" and "Password:". I'm happy to leave the Cancel and Unlock buttons as they are.

Comment: That did it! Man, you are awesome!!! How d'you even know about these things??  
Now, I just have to figure out how to change white on the initial screen that comes before the password screen, and the PowerOff dialogue boxes.

Comment: Added a new screenshot now. Hope it makes sense.
I already edited .login-dialog-prompt-label { color: and that sorted out the sencond screen.
Just this bit that seems to be hanging around.

Comment: But that's the same snippet that changes the text colour of "Password:" ??
If I edit that, it changes just that.

Comment: That's worked, man. It's absolutely beautiful, thanks ever so much.