# How to make Power Off window dark?

Tags: gnome

How do I make the **Power Off** window dark? Basically, it's inverting the current colours. i.e. make background dark, text white.

With another member's help, I've already done this to the login screens. For this one also, I'd imagine `gnome-shell.css` needs to be edited, just don't know which sections.

[image: Power Off window in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your this question is a followup Question of this https://askubuntu.com/a/1171364/739431 and you are aware of the warning

***Be Careful while editing the gdm3.css or its original file.. small mistakes in code.. will not let you login.. you need special support to bring back things to normal.. Proceed with your own.***

I think below changed codes from the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/communitheme/gnome-shell.css` will do what you are looking for..

for easy Identification I have given 4 colors green, blue, yellow & orange..

```
.end-session-dialog-shutdown-icon {
  color: green;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px; }
```

Other

```
.modal-dialog, .prompt-dialog, .audio-device-selection-dialog, .access-dialog, .geolocation-dialog, .extension-dialog, .inhibit-shortcuts-dialog, .nm-dialog {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

Other

```
.modal-dialog-linked-button {
  border-right-width: 1px;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  background-color: orange;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
  color: #3D3D3D;
  icon-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; }
```

[image]

Please note that this may change the behaviour of other popus or menu colors because of the combined code..

for example:

```
.modal-dialog, .prompt-dialog, .audio-device-selection-dialog, .access-dialog, .geolocation-dialog, .extension-dialog, .inhibit-shortcuts-dialog, .nm-dialog
```

Edit:

```
.modal-dialog-linked-button {
  border-right-width: 1px;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  background-color: orange;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
  color: cyan;
  icon-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; }
```

Look for color `Cyan`

[image]

Comment: Great stuff, mate. Thanks again.
Apologies if I've missed this out...but is there a way to change the text colour? I've followed your instructions and changed the background colour to dark.

Comment: Yes, I did..
Just seen your edit (Cyan colour), I'll get on that :). Thank you!

Comment: How do you change the background colour of only the shutdown button without changing the background colour of other buttons (Cancel and Restart)?

Comment: @itakura.. I have tried what you are looking for.. but at my knowledge I could not achieve that..