# How to create a circular framed-user-icon{} in unlock and login screen

Tags: gnome, themes, css

According to this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_circles.asp), I should be able to create a circle in CSS with:

```
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I implemented this to change the `.framed-user-icon` in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` from

```
/* Auth Dialogs & Screen Shield */
.framed-user-icon {
  background-size: contain;
  border: 2px solid #eeeeec;
  color: #eeeeec;
  border-radius: 3px; }
  .framed-user-icon:hover {
    border-color: white;
    color: white; }
```

to:

```
/* Auth Dialogs & Screen Shield */
.framed-user-icon {
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #eeeeec;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block; }
  .framed-user-icon:hover {
    border-color: white;
    color: white; }
```

But this did not work. Instead, I had to change `border-radius: 50%;` to `border-radius: 50px;` for it to work. Why is this the case?

Also I could not change the size of the the circular `.framed-user-icon{}`; changing the values of the `length` and `breadth` did not work. Why is this the case and how do I change the size of the circular `.framed-user-icon{}`.

I am trying to get this layout in the unlock screen:

[image: unlock screen]

**Update:**
Using the very nice GDM theme referred by @PRATAP, [High Ubunterra 2.4](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1207015/), I was able to adapt that css file to give this unlock screen login look:

[image: unlock screen status]

Questions:

1. May I know the variable name in ubuntu.css that styles "Username"? I am having difficulty locating it. This is to allow me to figure out how to shift "Username" to be below `.framed-user-icon{}`.
2. I would like the password entry to be centered, presently it is left-aligned. I have been tried using `text-align: center;` in `StEntry {}` but that did not work. I am out of ideas. What must I do to enforce a center-aligned password entry?
3. To center the position of the widgets, presently I am using command `margin: 0 0 0 100px;` to shift the widget right. But this approach is very manual, unproductive and approximate. Typically, GUIs have simple command(s) to center align a widget within a container. May I know what is the correct way to center-align `.framed-user-icon{}` and `.login-dialog-message-warning{}`?

**Update1:** This diagram shows that using cmd `text-align=center` in a css file is able to return a center-aligned password entry. [Code tester](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/best-code-editor/css-forms-example-9) 
[image: text-align=center should work]
I did explore explicitly adding:

```
input[type=password] {
  text-align: center; }
```

or adding this command to :

```
/* Entries  password input prompt */
StEntry {
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #161616;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  border:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  selection-background-color: #dd4814;
  selected-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;  }
  StEntry:focus {
    /*box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
    /*border-color: rgba(154, 154, 142, 0.5);*/ }
  StEntry:insensitive {
    color: #949796;
    /*border-color: #363633;
    box-shadow: none;*/ }
  StEntry StIcon.capslock-warning {
    icon-size: 16px;
    warning-color: #f57900;
    padding: 0 4px; }
```

But strangely, neither of them would work. I wonder why?

Comment: if possible,  can you explain with a sketch? how do you want it with arrow marks?

Comment: I used this [simulator](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_circles) to try out the above commands. They worked there. But I don't get the effect I want appearing in `ubuntu.css`. The size of  `.framed-user-icon{}` seems somehow fixed. It can't get bigger or smaller. changing `border-radius: 50px` I could only transit it from a square shape to a circle shape but the size is always fixed. I am trying to make a bigger login user icon for my Ubuntu 18.04 system, I want the icon to be circular (instead of the present square shape) and have it center aligned.

Comment: css files can only makeup the face.. size of face is configured by source code.. you can not acheive such makups to the source easily..

Comment: @PRATAP I see. My question two can't be fixed in ubuntu.css. Can you explain to me why `border-radius: 50%` could not work? Btw, where is the source code reading this ubuntu.css? I just added the image showing what I am trying to do.

Comment: Hi.. the style in image is possible.. let me get some files.. will be back..

Comment: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1207015/ install this gdm theme.. and tweak it to your needs..

Comment: Tried it. It's username appears on the right of `.framed-user-icon{}`. What must I do to bring the username below `.framed-user-icon{}`?

Comment: Hi.. Will try.. never tried.. mean while you can search gdm themes.. photos.. which have username field below the user icon..

Comment: @PRATAP Thanks. I will continue to work on it at my end.

Comment: @PRATAP I have shown my progress but quite stuck from this point onward. Can you advice me on how to resolve my questions? Thanks.

Comment: Hi the user logo and username right side of it are hard coded... with css file you can just make up them with colors bold text increase text height etc.. but you cant change the user name from right side of user logo

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/gnome-shell-lock-screen-redesign you need to wait or if you have enough skills which i dont have... edit source code to bring the user name fro right side of user logo to bottom..

Comment: this link may help https://askubuntu.com/q/1171332/739431 for other points you mentioned in question

Comment: @PRATAP No rush, can wait. Appreciate your invaluable helps. Me think I kind of hit my present limit. ;) Will slowly digest the new links.... Wow...the new GDM looks awesome....kudos to the dev. team...

Comment: @PRATAP This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) introduced the various types of css input widgets. This other [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_align.asp) explained how html input tags enforce alignment. I believe the html tag of the password widget could look like this `<input name="StEntry" type="password"  align="left|right|middle|top|bottom >`. If so, the answer to my Update Question 2  will be I can't achieve it by amending ubuntu.css but by amending the file that reads from/uses ubuntu.css.

Comment: I think source code uses java scripts..

Comment: @PRATAP I found that  `test-align=center` in css file does the same as  align="middle" in html. Also, the former has priority over the latter. So technically,  source file access is not needed. Just don't understand why it has not worked for the Ubuntu 18.04 GDM. :( See my Update1)

Comment: @PRATAP I discovered `.login-dialog-username{}` and `.user-widget-label{}` are the selectors for the Username.